# SAP UI5 embed manifest.json right

Tags: sapui5, manifest

I just wrote the description file for my UI5 application. 
Now I have these questions:

1. Where and how can I embed the manifest.json in my project correctly?
2. How can I test if it's working fine? (correctly embedded)
3. Is the "start_url": "" similar to initialPage of the index.html?

Many thanks for your guidance,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Usually*, the `manifest.json` file  (aka. "Application Descriptor") is put into the same folder as [where the `Component.js` file is located](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/003f755d46d34dd1bbce9ffe08c8d46a.html). The component will look for the file name "manifest.json" in the same folder. If the descriptor is located somewhere else or has a different file name, assign the relative URL of the file to the [`manifestUrl`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.component) in the component factory function [like this](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/346599f0890d4dfaaa11c6b4ffa96312.html#loio346599f0890d4dfaaa11c6b4ffa96312__ul_pht_yq1_qk), which is recommended to do so anyway because it ...

   - loads the descriptor file [before creating the component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxV8X.gif) (same as `manifestFirst`) allowing us to preload dependencies and [model data](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/26ba6a5c1e5c417f8b21cce1411dba2c.html) to improve the initial loading time.
   - makes specifying the `name` of the component [redundant](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/958ead51e2e94ab8bcdc90fb7e9d53d0.html).

     > You can either pass the name of the component or the URL of the descriptor file to load [the component] via the descriptor.
2. To see if the file is correctly embedded, run the app and see if e.g.

   - the `rootView` is loaded,
   - models (for example ResourceModel for i18n) are set to the component instance,
   - custom resources assigned to `sap.ui5/resources` are loaded, etc. etc..
     → Make sure to include (or in case of `manifestFirst`/ `manifestUrl`, [don't be tempted to remove](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1398)) manifest declaration in the [component metadata](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/0187ea5e2eff4166b0453b9dcc8fc64f.html).
3. The `"start_url"` is purely advisory and [meant for the web standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/#start_url-member) rather than for UI5. It's telling the browser where to look for the initial page when the user starts the web app.

To learn more about the descriptor file, take a look at the developer guide such as ["Descriptor for Applications"](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html) or as a summary, [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/8f93bf2b2b13402e9f035128ce8b495f.html).